# get the html of .ctp file in CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have deployed an app using `cakephp`. Now i have some data which i want to render on some logic. This data should be showed as a page including some inputs and other fields.

One thing is to do this in `javascript` side but it will not be a suitable option to make a whole html in `javascript`.

Other solution on which i am working is to pass the data to the `.ctp` file. Get the `html` and pas this to my content.

I am trying to do this as

`$html = $this->render('myview');
$this->set('html', $view);`

but it render the myview as a page not as html to be shown to my view.

Comment: For one, you've rendered your view into a variable called `$html`, but then set it using a variable called `$view`. So that's not going to help. But it seems you might not be aware that your `.ctp` files can contain all the HTML and PHP that you want. They are just specially named PHP files, executed the same way, except that there are some variables sent to them from the caller (whatever you `set`, plus helpers). So, instead of trying to solve how to render one view and then include that in another, take a step back and explain what you're really trying to do, and we'll help you with that.

Comment: okay let me explain further. how to get the html of a ctp file in your controller.? I think this is simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Follow the code to achieve the same,  (this code in your controller's method/action)

```
        //Variables used in view
        $data = $this->Admins->newEntity();

        // create a builder
        $builder = $this->viewBuilder();

        // configure as needed
        $builder->setLayout('default');
        $builder->setTemplate('/Admins/login');   //Here you can use elements also
        $builder->setHelpers(['Html']);

        // create a view instance
        $view = $builder->build(compact('data'));   //Pass the variables to the view

        // render to a variable
        $output = $view->render();

        //Print output
        pr($output);
        die;
```

Comment: i am already showing a layout and a view. i dont want to set a new layout i just want to get the html of a ctp file

Comment: That's just an example, if you want only the HTML of a CTP file then you can set layout as false **$builder->setLayout(false);** , in this way you will have only the HTML of the CTP file

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question and comments, you want to render something in a certain place of your view, but you want to put code for that component in separate .ctp file. CakePHP already has built in tools to achieve this - Elements and Cells.

Elements are reusable pieces of code, which resides in `src/Template/Element` directory. To create an element, simply create new .ctp file (eg. myelement.ctp) in this directory, and output it in your main view using:

```
<?= $this->element("myelement") ?>
```

Elements have access to variables passed to view from which are called, but if needed, one can also pass variables as second argument:

```
<?= $this->element("myelement", ["somevariable" => "somevalue"]) ?>
```

On the other hand, you have also Cells, which should be used in need to create an reusable component which depends on some logic which should be separated from controller code. Cell consists of two parts - a Cell class, which is equivalent for controller, and template file. It can be baked by:

```
bin/cake bake cell Sample
```

This command will create `src/View/Cell/SampleCell.php` and `src/Template/Cell/Sample/display.ctp` files. In first of them, a standard controller logic can be performed. In second, you can put HTML and access to passed variables. Cell can be rendered into a view by using:

```
<?= $this->cell("Sample") ?>
```

More info can be found in docs:

[Elements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements)

[View Cells](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)

Comment: Hi yeah i want to achieve this but i have a `php` loop in the ctp file which makes the list `<li>`. element is just a static html and i cannot get more of it.

Comment: CakePHP elements are not static html - you can put php code into them.

Comment: If @Szymon's suggestions haven't helped you solve it yet, maybe show us more than 2 lines of your code, and we'll be able to give more precise help.